# Recall a var inside onAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smoothstate.js

I'm trying to recall some variable events after page load.

I'm using smoothstate.js so I load my page dynamically with ajax.
The code works only on page refresh if i simply put the code inside onAfter, so I think that there is another way to do that.

I want to recall this:

```
    var snapper = new Snap({
    element: document.getElementById('content'),
    hyperextensible: false
  });

  var addEvent = function addEvent(element, eventName, func) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      return element.addEventListener(eventName, func, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
      return element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, func);
    }
  };

  addEvent(document.getElementById('open-left'), 'click', function(){
    if( snapper.state().state=="left" ){
      snapper.close('left');
    } else {
      snapper.open('left');
    }
  });

  var snapper2 = new Snap({
    element: document.getElementById('content'),
    hyperextensible: false
  });

  $('#open-right').click(function(){
    if( snapper2.state().state=="right" ){
      snapper2.close('right');
    } else {
      snapper2.open('right');
    }
  });

  })(document, window.navigator, "standalone");
```

Inside this:

```
onAfter: function($container, $newContent) {
  // Recall plugin here

}
```

How can I do that?